# How can I track the parcel (Australia Post) once button is clicked in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to program a tracking system in C# (a windows application.)
What I'm trying to do is once button is clicked, IE (or chrome) is opened,
and track the items with numbers in the textbox automatically.
The site is `http://drc.edeliver.com.au/track/`
In the Australia post page, I want my number in the `*Enter tracking number*` automatically.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tracking sites often have a method of supplying a direct link to track something. In your case, for Australia post, it is like this:

```
http://auspost.com.au/track/track.html?id=1234
```

where 1234 is the tracking number.

To run an application (or url etc), you can use the following:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://auspost.com.au/track/track.html?id=1234");
```

So in your button handler you could have something like this:

```
string trackingNumber = trackingTextBox.Text;
string trackingLink = string.Format("http://auspost.com.au/track/track.html?id={0}", trackingNumber);
// Launch browser to url
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(trackingLink);
```